# Getting LIMIT value from table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, sql-insert

I am trying to run an insert statement in SQL for a fixed time. So far I have tried this and it works as I wanted, but is there any way to combine these two parts ?

```
INSERT INTO assigns (AgencyName, ScoutID, RequestID)
SELECT AgencyName, ScoutID, RequestID
FROM employs NATURAL JOIN Scout NATURAL JOIN agency_response NATURAL JOIN Request
WHERE Answer = @option AND AgencyName = @agency_name
LIMIT 1;
```

This inserts into assigns table 1 time. But I have the desired LIMIT value in the table that I obtained from NATURAL JOIN's. In this case it is stored in NumberOfScouts. Below returns 8 for example and I want to limit to 8.

```
SELECT NumberOfScouts
FROM employs NATURAL JOIN Scout NATURAL JOIN agency_response NATURAL JOIN Request
WHERE Answer = @option AND AgencyName = @agency_name;
```

Is there any way to get the value of integer used in LIMIT from the table I used. I tried to put LIMIT to upper parts of query but it gave syntax error.

Comment: Tip of today: Forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction. Be in control, specify the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
WITH asr as (
      SELECT ?.AgencyName, ?.ScoutID, ?.RequestID, ?.NumberOfScouts,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ?.AgencyName) as seqnum
      FROM employs e JOIN
           Scout s
           ON ?? JOIN    -- JOIN conditions here
           agency_response ar
           ON ?? JOIN    -- JOIN conditions here
           Request r
           ON ??         -- JOIN conditions here
     WHERE ?.Answer = @option AND ?.AgencyName = @agency_name
    )
SELECT ?.AgencyName, ?.ScoutID, ?.RequestID
FROM asr
WHERE seqnum <= NumberOfScouts;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases which are abbreviations of table names.
- Qualify all column references so you -- and everyone else -- knows what table columns come from.
- Use `JOIN` with `ON`/`USING` so you know what columns are used for the `JOIN`s.

I describe `NATURAL JOIN` as an abomination because it does not use properly declared foreign key relationships for the `JOIN` condition.  Plus, most of my tables have `createdAt` and `createdBy` columns which would confuse the so-called "natural" join.

Comment: in ?.AgencyName, ?.ScoutID etc. meaning of "?" is alias not table right ? i.e Can i replace ?.AgencyName with e.AgencyName

Comment: Yes.  The `?` is for the table alias.